# Is there anything called conditional access control in solidity?

Tags: erc-721, solidity-0.8.x, openzeppelin-contracts, access

So here is my problem .

I have 2 users of my DApp : Admin and User

Admin is the contract owner and can access admin panel of my DApp . User is a normal user having something like a *conditional access* . The contract owner creates a transactionId ( similar to a token Id ) and corresponding to that Id I have mapped submitters and approvers . Submitter submits a transaction and approver approves that transaction after transaction has been submitted by the submitter .

**Now my idea is that the User's UI will somewhat be like he gets 2 lists :**
one containing transactions that he has to submit ( the admin granted him the role of submitter for those particular transaction Ids ) and ,
the other list is containing transactions that he has to approve ( the admin granted him the role of approver for those particular transaction Ids ) .

I'll share the code snippet here :

```
    contract MyContract {
        constructor() {
            admin = msg.sender;
            _grantRole(ADMIN,admin); // when contract is deployed ADMIN role is granted to msg.sender i.e. the deployer of the contract 
        
        }
    mapping(uint256 => address[]) public transactionIdToApproversArray; 
    mapping(uint256 => address[]) public transactionIdToSubmittersArray; 

    function submit(uint256 _transactionId, address[] memory _submitters ,address[] memory _approvers,uint256 _numConfirmationsRequired) external onlyRole(ADMIN) {
        
        require(_approvers.length>1,"Approvers required must be greater than 1");
        require(_numConfirmationsRequired>0 && _numConfirmationsRequired<=_approvers.length,"Num of confirmations are not in sync with the number of approvers");
        for (uint i = 0; i < _submitters.length; i++) {
            require(_submitters[i] != address(0),"address cannot be a zero address");
            _grantRole(SUBMITTER,_submitters[i]);
// do something
        }

        for (uint i=0;i<_approvers.length;i++){
            require(_approvers[i] != address(0),"address cannot be a zero address");
            _grantRole(APPROVER,_approvers[i]);
// do something 
        }
    }
    }
```

The problem that I currently have is when I pass an array of submitters and approvers , they are set as universal submitters and approvers ( means they have become submitters and approvers in the context of whole contract , I want to limit submitters' and approvers' access to a particular transaction Id only ) .
I've used Openzeppelin's access control right now .

Thank you in advance .

Comment: How did you define `SUBMITTER` and `APPROVER`? How do you check the assigned role?

Comment: I defined like this earlier :   mapping(bytes32 => mapping(address => bool)) public roles;  This says role when mapped to an address returns boolean .
But after spending a good amount of time thinking what could be done I came up with this :  mapping(bytes32 => mapping(address =>mapping(uint256 => bool))) public roles; 
I want to ask you is the second way of limiting role access okay or I can do something better ? The second way says that bytes32 role is mapped to an address and that address is mapped to a transaction Id , the returned value of this triple nested mapping is a boolean .

Comment: e.g. first way -> roles[role_in_bytes32][wallet_address] = boolean_value;

This way of doing had a problem that the submitter or approver role was being granted in the context of whole contract but I wanted that role should be given to an address depending on transaction Id . So I came up with second way .

e.g. second way -> roles[role_in_bytes32][wallet_address][transaction_id] = boolean_value;
This way an address will be granted/revoked role depending on a transaction Id .

Comment: You should use OpenZeppelin `AccessControl`. It is tested and works. A different approach might work but I can't verify without the code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create conditional access control for submitters and approvers based on transaction IDs, you can create a `Transaction` struct with a mapping for both `submitters` and `approvers`:

```
struct Transaction {
    uint256 numConfirmationsRequired;
    mapping(address => bool) submitters;
    mapping(address => bool) approvers;
}
```

To assign submitters and approvers for a specific transaction ID, you can use a function like this:

```
function submit(uint256 _transactionId, address[] memory _submitters, address[] memory _approvers, uint256 _numConfirmationsRequired) external onlyAdmin {
    // Validation checks here...

    Transaction storage t = transactions[_transactionId];
    t.numConfirmationsRequired = _numConfirmationsRequired;

    for (uint i = 0; i < _submitters.length; i++) {
        t.submitters[_submitters[i]] = true;
    }

    for (uint i = 0; i < _approvers.length; i++) {
        t.approvers[_approvers[i]] = true;
    }
}
```

This approach allows you to limit the access of `submitters` and `approvers` for a specific **transaction ID**

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem :

```
contract MyContract {
    address public admin; // contract owner

    mapping(bytes32 => mapping(address =>mapping(uint256 => bool))) public roles; // admin , approver , submitter // by doing this an address has a certain role for a certain ID only .
    enter code here

    // 0xdf8b4c520ffe197c5343c6f5aec59570151ef9a492f2c624fd45ddde6135ec42
    bytes32 private constant ADMIN = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("ADMIN")); // admin
    
    // 0x5ff1fb0ce9089603e6e193667ed17164e0360a6148f4a39fc194055588948a31
    bytes32 private constant APPROVER = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("APPROVER")); // approver

    // 0x12b80c3c1a8f58857e0e80e1961585f574502e089ca974eb9fcf05cf904fe012
    bytes32 private constant SUBMITTER = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("SUBMITTER")); // submitter 

    constructor() {
        admin = msg.sender;
        _grantRole(ADMIN,admin,876578867866876); // when contract is deployed ADMIN role is granted to msg.sender i.e. the deployer of the contract 
    }
function _grantRole(bytes32 _role , address _account,uint256 _formId) internal {
    roles[_role][_account][_formId] = true;
    emit GrantRole(_role,_account,_formId);
}

modifier onlyRole(bytes32 _role,uint256 _formId) {
    require(roles[_role][msg.sender][_formId],"not authorized");
    _;
}

function grantRole(bytes32 _role , address _account,uint256 _formId) external onlyRole(ADMIN,876578867866876) { // admin grants a certain role to a certain address
    require(_account != address(0),"address cannot be a zero address");
    _grantRole(_role,_account,_formId);
}

function revokeRole(bytes32 _role , address _account,uint256 _formId) external onlyRole(ADMIN,876578867866876) { // admin can revoke a certain role from a certain address anytime he wants
    require(_account != address(0),"address cannot be a zero address");
    roles[_role][_account][_formId] = false;
    emit RevokeRole(_role,_account,_formId);
}
    event GrantRole(bytes32 indexed role , address indexed account,uint256 _formId);
event RevokeRole(bytes32 indexed role , address indexed account,uint256 _formId);


    }
```

This approach worked for me . However , I am open to suggestions on how can I make this contract better .